# Oculus rift cv1 - some games are not displaying video in the headset

Tags: oculus-rift, steam-vr

I have selected "Unknown sources" in my settings. I can see every game i download from the oculus store but when i try to play for example Affected or other steam vr games i only hear the audio, i do not see any image.
I have a white light in the headset when running games and i have every cable properly conected.

Has anyones faced this problem?

Thanks